# Finding possible inverses of a modulo function

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse, euclidean-algorithm

I know how to find $one$ inverse via the euclidean algorithm, but I can't figure out how to find more of them.

For example:

Find an inverse $x$, of $57$ $modulo$ $100$
Or an $x$ such that $57x ≡ 1$ modulo 100

I got the answer $-7$ from the euclidean algorithm, but then the domain of x is restricted to be between $0$ and $100$. I know $93$ works, but not how I would go about finding that on paper.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Any two inverses will be congruent mod $100$.

Comment: **Hint** 93 = 100-7

Comment: you can write $\frac{1}{57} and adding or subtracting 100 to the numerator until we get a integer number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get one answer $x=-7$ then all the others can be obtained by using the fact that $x \equiv -7 \pmod{100}$. Thus every such $x$ is of the form $x=-7+100t$, where $t\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: errrm... $\bmod 100$ *cough*

Comment: @AlexR thanks for pointing the typo.

Comment: Man that was really simple. I feel dumb now haha. Thanks for the help.